# How do I approve a task using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a functionality implemented on a task list.

When I press a button, the selected tasks are approved. In the task list, the fields are updated correctly. The task is also correctly updated in the workflow log.

The problem is that the workflow does not continue and the task associated with the next participant is not created. To update the tasks I use the following code.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Test");
var item;
for (item in selectedItems)
{
        var listitem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
        listitem.set_item('Completed',true);
        listitem.set_item('PercentComplete',1);
        listitem.set_item('FormData','Completed');
        listitem.set_item('Status','Approved');
        listitem.set_item('WorkflowOutcome','Approved');
        listitem.update();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
What do I have to do to get the approval to continue normally?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working manged code:

// edit
in the first version i have removed, in my opinion, useless lines of code, (now commented) and i thought that `SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus` is different from `Status` but they are the same fields.

```
ht["Completed"] = "TRUE";
ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
//ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
ht["Status"] = "Completed";
//ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)elevWeb.Language, false), Strings.WorkflowStatusCompleted, new object[0]);
ht["WorkflowOutcome"] = outcome;
//ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = outcome;
ht["TaskStatus"] = outcome;
ht["FormData"] = outcome;
```

so i think that you need to change your code like this:

// edit

the thing is that you have to set status to `Completed` but your `FormData` and `WorkflowOutcome` to your proper workflow outcome, that is `Approved`

```
var listitem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
listitem.set_item('Completed',true);
listitem.set_item('PercentComplete',1);
listitem.set_item('Status','Completed');
listitem.set_item('FormData','Approved');
listitem.set_item('WorkflowOutcome','Approved');
listitem.update();
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn´t work. 
I get an error telling me that the field "TaskStatus" does not exist.

Comment: happy to hear that. mark as answered if it resolves your issue :)